# Run code on all Java annotations during runtime

Tags: java

I would like to execute code during runtime on all annotated fields, including fields in sub-classes. As a minimal example:

```java
class X {
    // A custom annotation on `x`.
    @MyAnn
    int x = 0;

    Y y = new Y();
}

class Y {
    @MyAnn
    int y = 1;

    // ...
}
```

Now, what I need is an iterator over every `MyAnn` in `X`, i.e. `x` and `y.y`. Imagine I want to print them out:

```java
for (ann : anns) {
    System.out.println(/* annotation */);
}
```

(Prints out `0`, `1`).

Basically, there are a few parts of this that I don't know enough Java for:

- Getting every instance of an annotation
- Getting the value of an annotated field

Thank you!

Comment: But... I also fear this may be almost an XY problem, so please let me know if this is not "idiomatic" Java. I come from a long Rust background, and I feel like I'm just trying to replace derive macros in this sense.

Comment: If you think it may be an XY problem, you may want to mention the Y.

Comment: one option is to write an annotation processor

Answer (score 0):

You can scan a class's fields and their annotations via reflection. Here's a basic recursive implementation:

```
static void scan(Object o) throws IllegalAccessException {
    if (o == null) return;
    
    for (Field field : o.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
        if (field.getAnnotation(MyAnn.class) != null) {
            System.out.println(field.get(o));
        }
        if (!field.getType().isPrimitive()) {
            scan(field.get(o));
        }
    }
}
```

[**Ideone Demo**](https://ideone.com/kfuvZz)

This doesn't handle edge cases like inherited fields, private fields and circular references, but it should be enough to get you started.

Answer (score 0):

> Getting every instance of an annotation

```
MyAnn annotation = field.getAnnotation(MyAnn.class);
```

And then you can call a property value you have define in your annotation

> Getting the value of an annotated field

```
X instance = new X();
...
field.setAccessible(Boolean.TRUE);
int value= field.getInt(instance);
```

For the list all annotations, you call the `getAnnotations` methods.
Read about [Java Reflection](https://www.baeldung.com/java-reflection), you will have a good understanding.